# Page editing gives an extra text widget

Tags: 8, nodes

When I try to edit a page that already added am getting an extra text area movable widget as shown in below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it a bug or an issue with the settings in for the content type page?

Comment: Looks like you have the number of values set to bigger than 1. Check your field settings. Or is multivalue required?

Comment: Oh yea  , i have `body` field in the **page**  **content type** have **unlimited** set to field settings. Thats y i guess , and i have already some pages created and its not allowing me to edit **Allowed number of values** to **1**

Comment: Do you have more than one value anywhere? You could directly edit in DB. Bit be carefull with that.

Comment: No for the **body** field as such , pls tell the db entry to be modified ?

Comment: It's the column "cardinality" in the "field_config" table. Set this to 1 for the body field.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your field's cardinality set to greater than 1. Change it to 1 and the problem should be fixed.

In case you already have data in the field but you are sure to only have one value stored per entity change the column "cardinality" in the "field_config" table manually to 1.

Comment: FYI am using drupal 8 , there is no such table as **field_config**

Comment: Oh damn. Sorry for that. Maybe you write a script for that instead of changing the db. I will look into that the next days. Busy right now.